# Iterate through Matlab axis array without extra variables?

Tags: matlab-figure

The "for a=SomeArray" code template works well for iterating through arrays (e.g. number, characters, cells).  It doesn't work for an array of axes e.g.,

```
faxes=get(gcf,'Children')
class(faxes)
for a=faxes
   class(a)
   size(a)
end
```

You bascially need to explicitly index into faxes using a counter.  If that was not the case, you'd be able to avoid faxes and the indexing variable, leading to much simpler code.  Is there some coding detail that I'm missing that prevents this?

I've posted this to:

- [Usenet](http://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.soft-sys.matlab/UgvrynGfWGs)
- [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31685015/iterate-through-matlab-axis-array-without-extra-variables)

Answer (score 0):

According to [Usenet](http://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.soft-sys.matlab/UgvrynGfWGs), the array `faxes` needs to be a row vector.  Since `get(gcf,'Children')` is a column vector, it needs to be transposed:

```
faxes=get(gcf,'Children')
class(faxes)
for a=faxes'
   class(a)
   size(a)
end
```